# A regex to fix the ActionController::TestCase HTTP deprecation warning

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading an app from rails 4 to rails 5.  I am getting the `ActionController::TestCase HTTP deprecation warning`. I know how to fix it. For instance, `get :show, id: 1, email: o@o.com` becomes `get :show, params: { id: 1, email: o@o.com }`, but the app dates from rails 2 and has many, many instances of the warning in over 50 controller specs. I am trying to develop a regex that works in `Sublime Text` that will fix most of the warnings. My first attempt is

```
Find: (get :[\w]*,)([^\n]*)
Replace : \1 params: { \2 }
```

This works in many cases but fails in the following ways

- It does not work if the `get` goes over more than one line. If it does go over one line, then the preceding line ends in `,\n`.

  - It does not work for `put`, `create` and the other http verbs
  - It does not work if there is another type of input e.g. `headers`.

The last case is not that important to me as  I have relatively few of these so can fix these manually.  Can someone suggest a find regex and Replace instruction that will fix most of the deprecation cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following process that works for multi-lines and for different http verbs. It does not work for more complex cases, like use of `header` information. It is a two step process:

```
Find: (get|post|put|patch|delete)( :\w+)((?:,\n?[^\n,]+)+)
Replace: \1\2, params: { \3 }
```

then

```
Find: params: { ,
then
params: {
```

This solved 95% of my deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but instead of a Regex I used Rubocop's Autofix feature:

http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_rails/#railshttppositionalarguments

`> bundle exec rubocop --rails --only HttpPositionalArguments --auto-correct`

That fixed a huge number of these deprecation warnings without causing any syntax errors.
Remember to set `TargetRailsVersion: 5.0` or higher, to enable that cop.

Comment: Thats interesting. It is too late to use it on my code, but I will keep an eye on the robocop autofix feature in future.